# Can ObjectDataSource use table-valued parameters

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, objectdatasource, table-valued-parameters

If an ASP.NET web page uses an [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx), can you configure it to use a stored procedure that uses table-value parameters?

User-defined type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[integer_list_tbltype] AS TABLE
(
 [n] [int] NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GeneralReport]  
@intList integer_list_tbltype READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM ...
END
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GeneralDataSource" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetDataByRange" 
    TypeName="MyProject.GeneralDataSetTableAdapters.GeneralViewTableAdapter" 
    >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="intList" />            
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I've tried hooking into the ObjectDataSource's Selecting event like this:

```
protected void GeneralDataSource_Selecting( object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e )
{
    var zeroList = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
    var tvp_definition = new[] {new SqlMetaData( "n", SqlDbType.Int )};
    var sqlDataRecord = new SqlDataRecord( tvp_definition );
    sqlDataRecord.SetInt32( 0, 0 );

    zeroList.Add( sqlDataRecord  );

    e.InputParameters[ "intList" ] = zeroList;        
}
```

But that just results in a "System.ArgumentException: UdtTypeName property must be set for UDT parameters." being thrown

Comment: To clarify, this is being used by a ReportViewer control. The rdlc files like to use DataSets to bind data to the report - that's why I'm using an ObjectDataSource

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you wish to do it this way. See this [blog post](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/) by Lenni Lobel and see if that works for you.

**UPDATE:**For reporting I use [this](http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2009/07/01/reporting-against-a-domain-model.aspx) technique as shown on Codebetter.com

Comment: I'm using an ObjectDataSource as this is being used by the ReportViewer control to display a report on the page

Comment: Plain old ADO.net code and selects returning result sets will suffice your report viewer needs. I am wondering why u need SQL UDT.

Comment: Oh ok. I want to pass in a varying number of parameters to filter the report.. eg. Just display Orders 1,2,4,6,4

Comment: That's an interesting article, maybe I'll end up using that instead. Thanks (will leave question unanswered for now in case someone can answer the original problem)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this is a possible solution (though it probably does fall into the 'horrible' category!)

Override the table adapter that was generated by the strongly-typed dataset. eg.

```
public class GeneralViewTableAdapter2 : GeneralViewTableAdapter
{
    public override GeneralDataSet.GeneralViewDataTable GetDataByRange( object intList )
    {
        try
        {
            return base.GetDataByRange( intList );
        }
        catch ( ArgumentException e )
        {
            foreach ( SqlParameter parameter in this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters )
            {
                if ( parameter.SqlDbType == SqlDbType.Structured )
                    parameter.TypeName = "integer_list_tbltype";
            }

            return base.GetDataByRange( intList );
        }
    }
}
```

Then update the Type attribute on the ObjectDataSource control to refer to this new class. eg. "MyProject.GeneralDataSetTableAdapters.GeneralViewTableAdapter2"

Would love to see a 'cleaner' answer than this!